# icCube - export report to Excel with formatted values

Tags: excel, iccube-reporting

I've created a report in icCube (icCube Server : 6.8.5 19-Dec-2018, icCube Reporting : 6.8.5 (5286)). In the report I've a table widget that shows calculated measures with formatted values. When exporting to Excel I want the have the formatted_values instead of the calulated values.

I've in my MDX at the bottom of the query :

```
CELL PROPERTIES STYLE, CLASSNAME, VALUE, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING
```

I expected this would tell icCube to use the formatted_values but I get the calculated values when exporting the data to Excel. In icCube 5 (icCube Reporting : 5.1.8 (6:2797), icCube Server : 5.1.8 01-Mar-2016) this would do the trick and I get the formatted_value in Excel. Is this behavior changed? And so, how do I tell icCube to use the formatted_value when exporting the data to Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about the pivot-table not exporting the value of the FORMAT_STRING property to Excel then this is fixed in icCube 6.8.7. Note that the reporting is assuming that (like any other chart) the FORMAT_STRING value can be understood by Excel.